# componentdidmount doesn't work with split function and setState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal that trigger only user click on a link, within the component I have this

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { from_date, to_date } = this.props;

    let from_date_str = from_date.split(' ')[0],
    to_date_str = to_date.split(' ')[0];

    console.log(from_date_str);
}
```

this is working but when I try to setState like

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { from_date, to_date } = this.props;

    let from_date_str = from_date.split(' ')[0],
    to_date_str = to_date.split(' ')[0];

    this.setState({
        from_date_obj : from_date,
        to_date_obj : to_date,
        from_date : from_date_str,
        to_date: to_date_str
    })

}
```

I will get error of `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`, sigh why is it so?

Comment: Is in both the case value of  `to_date` same?

Comment: put the `console.log(from_date, to_date);`  in the starting of function, and check the value, can you show the result of this ?

Comment: @MayankShukla yes I can.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a check for undefined.

```
let from_date_str = from_date && from_date.split(' ')[0],
    to_date_str = to_date && to_date.split(' ')[0];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**This variable ("from_date") must be a string.**

I think that your "from_date" is integer or null.

[Check split of document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: he is getting this error: `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: What's your value of "from_date"?